# .materia_chip() function not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I want to use chips so that user can add tags 
Below is my html code

```
<div class="chips chips-autocomplete">
<input type="text" autocomplete="true">
</div>
```

In  tag i have the following code

```
$('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
autocompleteData: {
  'Apple': null,
  'Microsoft': null,
  'Google': null
}
});
```

But when i check my browser console it says that

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_chip is not a function

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you call the material js library

Comment: Yes i called material cdn...but still it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the input tag. You only need the div:

```
<div class="chips chips-autocomplete"></div>
```

Then call the material_chip function inside this block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip({
    autocompleteData: {
      'Apple': null,
      'Microsoft': null,
      'Google': null
    }
  });
});
```

Solved the problem for me.